# Inject dynamically created script and html into a Component

Tags: angular

I need to implement a page that injects an html/script contained in an object retrieved in that component. Let's say that I have an article object that includes a embed_script field with a value like this:

```js
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://host/javascripts/api/file.js'></script>
<div class='Placeholder' style='width: 100%; height: 950px;'>
<object class='tb' width='100%' height='950' style='display:none;'>
<param name='host_url' value='http://host' /> <param name='embed_code_version' value='3' /> 
<param name='site_root' value='' />
<param name='name' value='test/Dashboard' />
<param name='toolbar' value='yes' />
<param name='filter' value=':original_view=yes'/>
<param name='customViews' value='no'/>
<param name='toolbar' value='yes' />
<param name='showAppBanner' value='false' /></object>
</div>
```

These codes are provided by the backend and they changes for every object so I should handle them dynamically.

How can I inject such a code dynamically in the view of the component?

Comment: So are you getting this back from an http call?

Comment: Yes, that component will retrieve an object from an API and that object contains this snippets that must be loaded in the view